# HTML/CSS Side By Side Columns

Tags: html, css

I've followed a couple of tutorials and can't seem to put the columnOne and columnTwo divs together without having them overlap. When using float: left the text just ends up on top of one another.

ps: any code clean up recommendations are much appreciated. I'm just starting out....

Thanks to any help out there!

```css
body {
  background-color:#666666;
}

h1 {
color: #0c7fcc;
}
   
h2 {
  color: #58abe2;}

h3 {
  color: #7498d3;}

h1, h2, h3 {
        border-style: solid;
        font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
        border-color: #bfbfbf;            
        width: 700px;}
        
.paraOne, .paraTwo {
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 700px;}
.paraOne {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Who Am I?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Where Am I From?</h1>
    <div class="columnOne">
    <p class="paraOne"> Sometimes a hard question to answer. As a military kid I moved around a lot and never really found a permanent place to call home. I lived in Atlanta the longest, although I live in Manhattan now.</p>
    </div> 
   
   
    <h2> What Do I Do For Fun?</h2>
    <div class="columnTwo">
    <p class="paraTwo">
I like to play music and go hiking. There aren’t as many outdoor places in the city, but whenever I can get out and see nature, I find myself in a better place.
    </div>
</p>
    
    
    
    
    <br>
</br>

<h3>Favorite Foods</h3>
    <ol>
     <li>Pizza</li>
     <li>Cereal</li>
     <li>Pasta</li>
    
    <h3>Places I’d Like to Travel</h3>
    </ol>
    <ul>
      <li>Japan</li>
      <li>Italy</li>
      <li>The Moon</li>
    </ul>

    
    
 <h3>What Are Your Favorite Bands?</h3>    

 <fieldset>
<legend>What Are Your Top Three Music Artists?</legend>
<label>#1<br />
<input type="text" name="one" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select><br /> 
<label>#2<br />
<input type="text" name="two" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select><br /> 
<label>#3<br />
<input type="text" name="three" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select>

<p>

<input type="submit" 
value="Submit" />
    
    </fieldset>
    
    
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is ensure the two column `div`s are not separated by an `h1` tag, but are neighboring tags in the document tree. Then, simply assign each roughly half the screen with `width:49% and display:inline-block;` with a new css class, `twoColumn`.

```css
body {
  background-color:#666666;
}

h1 {
color: #0c7fcc;
}
   
h2 {
  color: #58abe2;}

h3 {
  color: #7498d3;}

h1, h2, h3 {
        border-style: solid;
        font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
        border-color: #bfbfbf;}

.twoColumn {
        width:49%;
        display:inline-block;}

.paraOne, .paraTwo {
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
.paraOne {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Who Am I?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="twoColumn">
    <h1>Where Am I From?</h1>
    <p class="paraOne"> Sometimes a hard question to answer. As a military kid I moved around a lot and never really found a permanent place to call home. I lived in Atlanta the longest, although I live in Manhattan now.</p>
    </div> 
   
    <div class="twoColumn">
    <h2> What Do I Do For Fun?</h2>
    <p class="paraTwo">
I like to play music and go hiking. There aren’t as many outdoor places in the city, but whenever I can get out and see nature, I find myself in a better place.</p>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <br>
</br>

<h3>Favorite Foods</h3>
    <ol>
     <li>Pizza</li>
     <li>Cereal</li>
     <li>Pasta</li>
    
    <h3>Places I’d Like to Travel</h3>
    </ol>
    <ul>
      <li>Japan</li>
      <li>Italy</li>
      <li>The Moon</li>
    </ul>

    
    
 <h3>What Are Your Favorite Bands?</h3>    

 <fieldset>
<legend>What Are Your Top Three Music Artists?</legend>
<label>#1<br />
<input type="text" name="one" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select><br /> 
<label>#2<br />
<input type="text" name="two" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select><br /> 
<label>#3<br />
<input type="text" name="three" /></label><select name="genre">
<option value="rock">Rock</option> <option value="country">Country</option> <option value="hiphop">Hip-Hop</option> <option value="pop">Pop</option></select>

<p>

<input type="submit" 
value="Submit" />
    
    </fieldset>
    
    
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**CSS**

```
.container {
      display:flex;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columnOne">
    <h1>Where Am I From?</h1>
    <p class="paraOne"> Sometimes a hard question to answer. As a military kid I moved around a lot and never really found a permanent place to call home. I lived in Atlanta the longest, although I live in Manhattan now.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnTwo">
  <h2> What Do I Do For Fun?</h2>
    <p class="paraTwo">
      I like to play music and go hiking. There aren’t as many outdoor places in the city, but whenever I can get out and see nature, I find myself in a better place.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things differently here in order to have these columns side by side.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Remove h1 tags first-->

<div class="columnone">
    <!--HTML tags in here -->
</div>

<div class="columntwo">
    <!-- HTML tags here -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.columnone, .columntwo {
display:inline-block;
width: 50%;
}
```

Normally  tags have a default display of "block" which takes up 100% of the width of a "row" on a web page.  Using "display:inline-block" will put  tags side by side and you can specify the width of these tags by writing CSS.

Hope this information helps!